# Loading an flickr image with a search function in flash using AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, flickr

i have created a page 1024 x 850 and im trying to achieve when typing text into the search_txt and pressing the search_btn images should show on the main_mc but i keep getting the error "type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Search" and "call to a possibly undefined method Search"

i have three files to complied into creating the search on flickr. 
AS3 code:

```
import xml.*;
import flickr.*;
import fl.controls.*;


var search_txt:TextInput = search_txt;
var search_btn:Button = search_btn;

var search:Search = new Search() as Button;
var reader:RSSReader = new RSSReader();

var media:Namespace = new Namespace("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
default xml namespace = media;

function rssProcessed(event:Event):void
{
var imgLoader:Loader;
var thumbX:Number = 0;
var thumbY:Number = 65;

for(var i:uint = 0; i < reader.episodes.length(); i++)
{
    imgLoader = new Loader();
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(reader.episodes[i].thumbnail.@url));
    addChild(imgLoader);

    if(i%5 == 0 && i != 0)
    {
        thumbY += 80;
        thumbX = search_txt.x;
    }
    imgLoader.x = thumbX;
    imgLoader.y = thumbY;
    thumbX += 80;

    if(i >= 14)
    {
        break;
    }
}
trace(reader.episodes[0].thumbnail.@url);
}

function dataReady(event:Event):void
{
reader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, rssProcessed);
reader.processXML(search.feed);
}

function searchFlickr(event:MouseEvent):void
{
search.search(search_txt.text);
search.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataReady);
}

search_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, searchFlickr);
```

Import XML (file inside this folder is called RSSReader.as)

```
package xml
{
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

public class RSSReader extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
    public var feed:XML;
    public var episodes:XMLList;
    public var title:String;
    public var description:String;

    public function RSSReader()
    {
        xmlLoader = new URLLoader();
    }

    public function load(xmlReq:URLRequest):void
    {
        xmlLoader.load(xmlReq);
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
    }

    private function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        processXML(new XML(xmlLoader.data));
    }

    public function processXML(xmlData:XML):void
    {
        feed = xmlData;
        episodes = feed..item;
        title = feed.channel.title;
        description = feed.channel.description;
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
}
```

Import flickr (file inside this folder is called Search.as)

```
package flickr
{
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Search extends EventDispatcher
{
    private var req:URLRequest;
    public var info:URLVariables;
    private var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    public var feed:XML;

    public function Search()
    {

    }

    public function search(searchStr:String):void
    {
        req = new URLRequest("https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne");
        info = new URLVariables();
        info.format = "rss_200";
        info.tags = searchStr;
        req.data = info;
        loader.load(req);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataLoaded);
    }

    private function dataLoaded(event:Event):void
    {
        feed = new XML(loader.data);
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The Search class extends EventDispatcher, but you initialize it the search object as a Button. Search needs to extend Button if you want to use it as a button.

Comment: Hello, sorry for a late reply. i changed the following code to button
 'public class Search extends EventDispatcher' so it now reads 'public class Search extends Button' but that hasn't seemed to work. same error still appers

Comment: the first is line 9 column 12 which is this

    var search:Search = new Search()as Button;

the second is the same (line 9) but column 25

Comment: Is "Search" in the library or is it a class. If a class it needs to be imported, if in the library then it needs to have its "export for as" classname set. I'm confused now, but the cast "as Button" needs to match the extends of the class "Search". So if Search extends Button you are ok.

Comment: New update, i stupidly named my Flickr folder with a capital "F" which has got rid of the two error but brings back an additional one.

Line 9, Column 25 
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type fl.controls:Button to an unrelated type flickr:Search.

This is the line it affects; 

var search:Search = new Search()as Button;

Thankyou for you help as well

Comment: It probably should be "new Search() as Search" if your Search is just a class and not a button.